# how to show Notification settings option in Settings for iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode

Can anyone help me to show App Notification settings under Settings > Notification > MyApp, option like attached image.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to attach your image.

Answer (score 0):

In order to link to your custom notification setting screen, you must set providesAppNotificationSettings as a `UNAuthorizationOption` when you are requesting notification permissions in the app delegate.

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, add the following code:

`UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound, .providesAppNotificationSettings]) { ... }`

You also have to make sure to handle the callback for when the user selects on either way to get to your notification settings. Your app delegate or an extension of your app delegate has to conform to the protocol `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` so you can then implement the following callback method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, openSettingsFor notification: UNNotification?) {
    let navController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let notificationSettingsVC = NotificationSettingsViewController()
    navController.pushViewController(notificationSettingsVC, animated: true)
}
```